# How to read chrome console using python without selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I would like to read chrome's js console using Python3 without any webdriver such as selenium (bot detection and stuff).

I've tried Chrome DevTools Protocol python libraries such as chromewhip, pychrome and PyChromeDevTools, but I'm unable to read any data from the console.

I want to read Runtime.consoleAPICalled or Log.entryAdded, but I don't know how to implement these callbacks as the documentation for these libraries doesn't specify any of that. Also there are no examples to be found either.

Does anyone know how to properly access these events or some other library which provides it?

Comment: According to your description, the feeling is to forget to add `Runtime.enable`. Can you post your code?

Comment: Good guess, but I made sure I've enabled Network, Runtime, Log and Page. It's more about me not being able to understand how to access the callback events mentioned above using python (are they return values or do they modify objects in-place?).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to read Runtime.consoleAPICalled or Log.entryAdded, but I don't
> know how to implement these callbacks

The following assumes (per your question phrasing) that you're able to send and receive debug protocol messages on the stream that's open to the web debugger endpoint.

After you send debug protocol messages `Runtime.enable` and `Log.enable` messages, the `Runtime.consoleAPICalled` and `Log.entryAdded` "events" you are looking for are represented by messages you receive on the same debugging channel.

You may need to match the console event messages with the execution context (seen in the `Runtime.enable` response) by examining the `executionContextId` field in the received event messages.  The log events are not associated with any single execution context.   All of these "event" messages will have `Id=0`, which helps to recognize they're "event" messages and not response messages.

Here are a couple of sample messages received from Chrome (formatted as JSON with arbitrary field order):

Console API event message:

```
{
    "method": "Runtime.consoleAPICalled",
    "params": 
    {
        "type": "warning",
        "args": [
          {  "type": "string",
            "value": "Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys"
           }],
         "executionContextId": 1,
         "timestamp": 1618949706735.553,
         "stackTrace": 
         {
              "callFrames": [
                {
                  "functionName": "TA.j",
                  "scriptId": "206",
                  "url": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/44/10/util.js",
                  "lineNumber": 228,
                  "columnNumber": 26
                } ]
          }
       }
    },
    "id": 0
}
```

Log event message:

```
{
   "method":"Log.entryAdded",
   "params":
   {
      "entry":
      {
          "source":"javascript",
          "level":"warning",
          "text":"The deviceorientation events are blocked by permissions policy. See https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/blob/master/features.md#sensor-features",
          "timestamp":1.6189509536801208e+12
      }
   },
   "id": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@kundapanda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11132502/kundapanda) could you at least post a snippet of the code that worked for you.